# Reading from a private Nuget feed - .NET Core 3.1 Windows Docker Container

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget

Does anyone have any experience with developing microservices in Azure with the .NET Core 3.1 using Windows containers? I am running into an issue when 
I am trying to make my Dockerfile read from a private Nuget feed. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./Nuget.config ./
COPY ["MyService/MyService.csproj", "MyService/"]

ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER=0
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"my_private_feed", \"password\":\"my_personal_access_token\"}]}"

RUN dotnet restore "MyService/MyService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyService"
RUN dotnet build "MyService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

This dockerfile gives me a 401 Unauthenticated error even though I know the credentials I am providing are correct. 
I've also tried setting the user and password in my nuget.config file and that seems to work, but I don't want to have
to make a code change to update the password each time a token expires.
Any advice on how to move forward from here? Am I just not formatting the setting of the VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS variable properly?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in the past. I stopped using `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` and created the nuget.config on the fly

## First step: Create small helper executable

```
namespace DockerBuild
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Count() != 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Use it: dotnet dockerbuild.dll <username> <pat> <sourceUrl> <target>");
            }
            var user = $"{args[0]}";
            var pat = $"{args[1]}";
            var source = $"{args[2]}";
            var target = $"{args[3]}";

            var xml = $"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><configuration><packageSources><add key=\"YourFeedName\" value=\"{source}\" /></packageSources><packageSourceCredentials><YourFeedName><add key=\"Username\" value=\"{user}\" /><add key=\"ClearTextPassword\" value=\"{pat}\"/></YourFeedName></packageSourceCredentials></configuration>";
            using (var file = new StreamWriter(target))
            {
                file.WriteLine(xml);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this console program will be: `DockerBuild.exe`

## Second step: Run the executable on docker build

```
ENV devops_user=$user
ENV devops_pat=$pat
ENV devops_nuget_source=$nuget_source
RUN DockerBuild.exe %devops_user% %devops_pat% %devops_nuget_source% nuget.config
```

Now you have a `nuget.config` file in your folder structure and you only need to use (or copy) it and run your `dotnet build/publish` command(s)

> **Attention:**
>   This example was done on a windows machine with running docker for windows. On linux the call to `DockerBuild.exe` must be changed to use the environment variables without `%` and use linux equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker image probably doesn't have the [Azure Artifacts NuGet credential provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) installed. Its repo readme has a link to a [sample dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/blob/master/samples/dockerfile.sample.txt), which includes this line:

```
# download and install latest credential provider. Not required after https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/878
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash
```

Since your dockerfile is using a Windows base image, not Linux, you'll need to adapt it, but conceptually it's the same issue, the credential provider isn't installed (or NuGet doesn't know how to find it), so NuGet doesn't know how to authenticate to your feed.

edit: there's an issue asking how to install on a Windows docker image: https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/issues/169